# Dialog Fragment Bundle always null

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, dialogfragment

I just want to send data from Fragment to DialogFragment. In Fragment ;

```
 val fm = requireActivity().supportFragmentManager
            val dialog = DialogFragmentName()
            val arg :Bundle? =null
            arg?.putInt("num",75)
            dialog.arguments = arg
            dialog.show(fm,"TAG")
```

In DialogFragment ;

```
 val bundle :Bundle? = arguments
    if (bundle != null) {
        val number: Int? = bundle.getInt("num")
        Toast.makeText(context,number,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context,"Null",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
```

But it always gives me Null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to initialise your `Bundle`, it is set to `null` and trying to add data to `null` reference fails safely because of `?.` operator which ends up sending empty `Bundle`

```
val fm = requireActivity().supportFragmentManager
val dialog = DialogFragmentName().apply{
      arguments = Bundle().apply{
          putInt("num",75)
      }
  }
dialog.show(fm,"TAG")
```